# Sequence of real numbers that converges in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence of real numbers that converges to $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $A = \{ a_n | n \geq 0\}$. Show that

a) $\overline{A} = A \cup \{a\}$

b) $A^\circ = \varnothing$

I am familiar with the definitions of closure, interior, convergence, but I have no idea where to start/how to approach these questions. So without giving the answers away, how do I approach these questions?

Answer (score 0):

a) Prove that $a\in\overline A$. It will follow that $A\cup\{a\}\subset\overline A$. Then prove that if $x\notin A\cup\{a\}$, then $x\notin\overline A$.

b) If $x\in\mathring A$, then $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset A$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ (why?). But $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ is not countable.

Answer (score 0):

As to b), this uses a specific fact about $\Bbb R$: all open sets that are non-empty contain an interval and so are uncountable. As $A$ is countable it cannot contain any non-empty open set and so $A^\circ = \emptyset$.

a) is true, but requires a small argument; one inclusion is easy $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ is always true, and $a \in \overline{A}$ holds, because if $B_r(a)$ is a ball of any radius $r>0$ around $a$, by the convergence we know that for all $n$ beyond some $N$, $x_n \in B_d(r)$ so $A \cap B_r(a) \neq \emptyset$, so $a$ is an adherent point of $A$, and so lies in $\overline{A}$. But why is that the only point beyond $A$? If $b \in \overline{A}$ we know that for some sequence in $A$, so really, a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$, such that $a_{n_k} \to b$ (by picking $a_{n_k} \in B_{\frac{1}{k}}, a)$ and insuring increasingness in $n_k$ (I assume throughout that $A$ is infinite, or else we get a different argument: then $A$ is already closed and the sequence $a_n$ was eventually constant, so we add no new point)). But as limits are unique, $b=a$ then. So $\overline{A}=A \cup \{a\}$.